# JAVA: How can i check scope of "protected abstract method"?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in Java programming, so i can't test scope of `protected abstract method`.

**To check `protected method` i test this code:**

```
package A;
public class NewClassA {
protected String a(){ return "a"; }
}

// Main 
NewClassA a = new NewClassA();
String str = a.a();   // works fine

//New Package
package B;
import A.NewClassA;
public class NewClassB {
   NewClassA x = new NewClassA();
   String str = x.a();   // Error convert to a() to public
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "check scope of protected abstract method"? As I can see in the code everything works as it should. You marked ``NewClassA::a`` method as protected so it's accessible only for its subclasses and classes in the same package. Class ``NewClassB`` is in different package, so it cannot make a call to ``x.a()``.

Comment: ok this `protected method` and i can check if i do the same for abstract method it will force me to override method if i override i can read in the new package with no exception , so in this case their's no difference between public and protected @Kamil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `abstract` method is one that doesn't have a defined behavior. Instead, the abstract class's *children* define its behavior themselves. An abstract method can only be defined in an `abstract` class, which cannot be instantiated. For example, in package A:

```
package A;
public abstract class NewClassA {
    protected abstract String getString();
}
```

And:

```
package A;
public class NewClassB extends NewClassA {
    @Override
    protected String getString() { //Must be overridden by non-abstract child
        return "B";
    }
}
```

Then, somewhere within package B:

```
package B;
import A.*;
public class ProtectChecker {
   NewClassA x = new NewClassA(); //Cannot instantiate abstract NewClassA
   NewClassA y = new NewClassB(); //OK

   String str = y.getString();   //Error convert to getString() to public
}
```